# Add logback filter to included appender

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

In a Spring Boot application, we take advantage of the pre-configured Logback configuration from Spring by including these configuration files and then just configure the loggers, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>

    <logger name="com.bla.bla" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Now I would like to add a `ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter` to do some filtering, but I cannot figure out if it's possible to add this to the appender defined in the included files, since it looks like the filter must be attached to the appender configuration (according to the Logback documentation). Ideally I would like to have the filter configuration in my application configuration and not touch the pre-defined configuration from Spring, something like this:

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
    <evaluator> <!-- defaults to type ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.JaninoEventEvaluator -->
        <expression>return logger.equals("org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper") &amp;&amp; message.contains("duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"source_data_version\"");</expression>
    </evaluator>
    <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
    <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
</filter>
```

Is this possible somehow or do I really need to re-define the appender so to speak in my own configuration file?

I started looking into writing my own filter class, but it doesn't seem to help with this configuration issue, since the custom filter still needs to be added to the appender as far as I understand.

Comment: Could you come up with a solution for this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not - I had to extract the pre-defined configuration from Spring and include it in my configuration.